# Data from GoogleShortenAPI to Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-api, firebase-realtime-database

I got Alamofire request. I "give" shortenLink api longUrl, and it "gives" me back a shortUrl. Request works perfectly, but when it comes to passing data to Firebase request it shows me that it's nil.

```
var _longUrl: String!
var longUrl: String {
    if _longUrl == nil {
        _longUrl = ""
    }
    return _longUrl!
}
```

That's typical getter - setter

And the download function looks like:

```
func downloadData() {
    var parameters = ["longUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIQsQ2injLo&t=302s"]
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
        let result = response.result
        if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary <String, AnyObject> {
            if let name = dict["id"] as? String {
                self._shortUrl = name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So there is nothing hard. Everything works fine till I want to pass data to function that sends data to data base. It shows me nil in this function on both items.

```
func post() {
    let item1 = _longUrl
    let item2 = _shortUrl
    let post : [String: Any] = ["longUrl" : item1, "shortUrl": item2]
    let dataBaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    dataBaseRef.child("urls").childByAutoId().setValue(post)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you exactly see the items as nil? Could you try making the `post` a dictionary as:

```
let post: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [ 
      "longUrl": item1 as String,
      "shortUrl": item2 as String
]
```

Comment: I know You have to be very specific when you are telling Firebase what kind of data you are sending to data base, but this is just showing me nil on _shortUrl and _longUrl everywhere outside downloadData function.

Comment: Hmm. Your code seems perfectly fine to me. As I see you’ve declared `_shortUrl` outside the functions and calling it by self inside the function. Are you sure the `dict[“id”]` is assigned to `_shortUrl` via `name` variable?

Comment: when I print _shortUrl in downloadData func it shows me correct JSON data..